# YouTube iframe API - loading related videos on iframe instead of opening new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, iframe, youtube

Since YouTube has recently disabled the ability to hide related videos using the rel parameter, I am trying to get the clicked on related video and display it on the iframe instead of it opening it on a new tab and going to the official YouTube page.
I've tried injecting html code into the iframe html document to disable the target=_blank feature on the links but recently found out about the CORS problem.
Is there any way to grab the clicked link and display it on the iframe and remove the target=_blank option on the embeded iframe?

Comment: or, you can loop the video *by adding the `loop=1` parameter in the iframe*.

Comment: Yeah doesn't really solve my problem, because if the user has paused the video it still shows related videos and if they decide to click on another video it would just open a new tab and go to the video but I want to display that clicked video on my site instead of it opening a completely new tab. Thanks for the help though

Comment: forgemaster, or consider use a custom YouTube player.